# In Stratego, what happens if in the setup a player puts all six bombs in the front row but not behind the lakes?

Tags: stratego

Imagine a situation which is highly improbable in practice but still possible theoretically. A novice player in Stratego, when making his/her initial setup, has put all his/her six bombs in the front row. No bombs behind any of the two lakes, however. So, in other words: two adjacent bombs are on the left flank, two bombs on the right flank and two in the center.

I had been playing wonderful game of Stratego for a long time, but I am so afraid of the above mentioned setup I never dared to try it. Still, I wonder what the game rules say about it. Is this an immediate loss?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you can't move, you lose the game.

Here is an excerpt from the [rules](https://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/Stratego.pdf):

> If all of your movable pieces have been removed and you cannot move or attack on a turn, you must give up and declare your opponent a winner.

You have zero movable pieces and they are all removed so it is a loss.

Comment: There's one exception: if the opponent also has no moveable pieces, the game is a draw. In tournament games, if your last moveable piece has been captured and you therefore cannot move anymore, you can call the referee to check whether your opponent still has a moveable piece left.